# How to optimise a Redshift table with a SUPER data type column?

Tags: query-performance, optimization, datatypes, redshift

We currently have a small table in Redshift with 3 columns

```
col1 (id): varchar(36)
col2: varchar(36)
col3: SUPER
```

Where the SUPER column contains a dictionary which can vary in length.
The total size of the table is ~700,000 rows.

Simple SELECT statements with a WHERE clause (col1 = id_value_A)   seem to be resulting in very high CPU usage. INSERT statements also result in high CPU, although this is more expected as INSERTs aren't as performant in Redshift.

What would be the best way to optimise this?